# динамический подсчет результата js

Tags: javascript, html

Динамический подсчет в калькуляторе.Только ты вводишь любую цифру в первый и второй импут должно в отдельный параграф выводится сразу посчитанный результат. Помогите, не знаю как записать эту функцию!

```js
function calc(sel) {
  var a, b;
  a = parseInt(document.calk.first.value);
  b = parseInt(document.calk.second.value);
  switch (sel.getElementsByTagName('option')[sel.selectedIndex].value)
  {
    case '+':
   alert (a + b);
   break;
 case '-':
   alert (a - b);
   break;
 case '*':
   alert (a * b);
   break;
 case "/":
   if ((a === 0) || (b === 0)) {
     alert('Делить на ноль нельзя');
   }
   else {
     alert (a / b);
   }
   break;
    default: alert("неверный символ")
   break;
  }
}

function proverka(input){
  var value = input.value;
  var rep = /0/;
  if (rep.test(value)) {
 submitButton.disabled = 1;
 input.value = value;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="calk" name="calk">
  Введите первое число:
  <input name="first"  type="text" /><br /><br/>
  <select name="sel"  size="1">
 <option calss="opt" value="+">+</option>
 <option calss="opt" value="-">-</option>
 <option calss="opt" value="*">*</option>
 <option calss="opt" value="/">/</option>
  </select><br/><br/>
  Введите второе число:
  <input type="text" id="second" onkeyup="return proverka(this)"; value=""  /><br />
  <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Посчитать" onclick="calc(sel)"; return false; /><br/><br/>
   <p id="out">Результат:</p>
</form>
```

Comment: А если `a===0`, почему у вас делить-то нельзя?

Comment: было такое предыдущее задание

Comment: Т.е. ваша проблема только в том, как заменить alert на вывод в поле результата?

Comment: еще и регекс на проверку 0

Comment: нет, я не знаю как сделать, что бы автоматически выводился результат при вводе. Вот я написал для одной строки вывод,а от как сделать сразу подсчет не знаю

Comment: document.getElementById("calk").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  var inp = e.target;
  
  if (inp.tagName === "INPUT") {
    //var tr = inp.closest("tr");
    var tr = inp.parentElement.parentElement;
    tr.querySelector(".out").textContent = inp.value;
  }
});

Comment: я конечно понимаю, что `eval` это плохо, но в данном примере сократилось бы кол-во строк на 10-15

Comment: я очень плох в этом, хотел помощи попросить просто, это в универ задание

Comment: препод сказал именно так сделать, eval нельзя использовать

Comment: @DimaTabachniy eval -- зло, не надо его использовать в своём коде.

Comment: сказал что бы и там и там 0 был

Comment: @regent я тебе оскорбительного ничего не сказал. Если будет спокойнее, можешь мысленно добавить "имхо" к моим комментам

Comment: @Herrgott, мы стараемся тут поддерживать доброжелательное отношение ко всем участникам, вне зависимости от уровня их навыков. Пожалуйста, старайтесь писать комментарии по делу, не стоит уводить разговор в сторону от конкретной проблемы, связанной с кодом)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вывод результата**

Получаете поле вывода через `document.getElementById`.
Выводите туда текст результата через `innerText`.

```
function result(value) {
  document.getElementById('out')
    .innerText = value;
}
```

**Реакция на ввод**

Чтобы пересчёт осуществлялся при вводе аргументов, нужно обрабатывать события `change` или `input` полями ввода.

```
input.addEventListener('change', function(){/*...*/calc(sel);})
```

```js
function result(value) {
  document.getElementById('out')
    .innerText = value;
}

function calc(sel) {
  var a, b;
  a = parseInt(document.calk.first.value);
  b = parseInt(document.calk.second.value);
  switch (sel.getElementsByTagName('option')[sel.selectedIndex].value) {
    case '+':
      result(a + b);
      break;
    case '-':
      result(a - b);
      break;
    case '*':
      result(a * b);
      break;
    case "/":
      if ((a === 0) || (b === 0)) {
        result('Делить на ноль нельзя');

      } else {
        result(a / b);
      }
      break;
    default:
      result("неверный символ")
      break;
  }
}

function proverka(input) {
  var value = input.value;
  var rep = /0/;
  if (rep.test(value)) {
    submitButton.disabled = 1;
    input.value = value;
  }
}

function onInput() {
  calc(document.calk.sel);
}

document.calk.first.addEventListener('input', onInput);
document.calk.second.addEventListener('input', onInput);
document.calk.sel.addEventListener('change', onInput);
onInput();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="calk" name="calk">
    Введите первое число:
    <input name="first" type="text" value="1" /><br /><br/>
    <select name="sel" size="1">
      <option calss="opt" value="+">+</option>
      <option calss="opt" value="-">-</option>
      <option calss="opt" value="*">*</option>
      <option calss="opt" value="/">/</option>
  </select><br/><br/> Введите второе число:
    <input type="text" id="second" onkeyup="return proverka(this)" ; value="1" /><br />
    <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Посчитать" onclick="calc(sel)" ; return false;><br/><br/>
    <p id="out">Результат:</p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: код нужно вешать на событие `onchange` у инпута/инпутов

Comment: @дмытрык этот код не подойдет для `onchange`

Comment: Так вопрошающему надо, чтобы результат выводился при каждом изменении значения в инпуте

Comment: Нужна была "Реакция на ввод". Выше человек уже помог